# What are the properties of a numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x

Say I define a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
y=np.random.randn(100)
```

Then I can obtain what I call "properties" of the array like:

```
    y.shape
    y.max()
    y.min()
```

What other "properties" are available, and where can I find a list of what properties are available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dir(variable_name) on any python variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you mean by "properties" are the atributes and methods of the array. Each numpy array is an instance of the numpy.ndarray class and its complete list of atributes and methods may be found in the documentation:
https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html